# ipad html5 web app - can't click twice on button

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, redirect, safari

I've created 2 pages, a form page and a form confirmation page. This form will be used as a web app on an iPad. So i've added al the meta tags to these pages.

Like:  , ...

I've added the web app to our homescreen on the ipad by using Safari and add it to the homescreen.

When you fill in and submit the form, you are redirected to the confirmation page. The confirmation page redirects you automatically to the form page after 5 seconds.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function leave() {
           window.location.assign("http://www.growzer.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/beurs/");
      }
      setTimeout("leave()", 5000);
 </script>
```

It doesn't work to submit the form for a second time. The submit button keeps have its hover state.
I don't have this problem in a normal browser.

Does someone know what the problem is? And is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the form gets OK-response from the server before the redirecting to the confirmation page?

Comment: Yes it has.

This is the form

http://www.growzer.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/beurs/ On the first page you can choose between two forms "newsletter form" or "request a demo" form. Depending on which button you click, the div with the form is show (jquery hide and show). If you submit the form, you are redirect to the confirmation page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the form manually with the `formObject.reset()`-function. The way to do this is something like this:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
   // reset the form
   $(this).reset(); // reset is a native function so it might work a bit differently
   return true; // return false to cancel form action
});
```